# Block face camera in android app

Tags: android, webview, camera, crosswalk-runtime

I'm developing an app that allows users to take photos of places. However, I would only enable the back camera. As in the case of this app, take pictures with the 'selfie camera'(face camera) is not a cool experience (believe me).
The application is not native. It is a webview within the android. Points to a site that is at a particular address.
I would like to know how to block the 'selfie camera' of this app.
I tried a few options in AndroidManifest.xml but did not succeed.
For what I was trying to do was mistakenly force the face camera. And not to block it.
Follow my AndroidManifest.xml

The mistake is here:
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.diego.android.crosswalkdemo" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your app uses `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent to take the picture. Behind the scenes, it actually launches an external camera application, and you have little control over what this app will or won't do. But you can analyze the image file that you receive, and (depending on the camera app) you can verify that it's EXIF header indicates that the picture was taken timely, and using the back camera.

Comment: Even the application running on a webview?

Comment: Is there any policy that I can put in the main class or AndroidManifest that  force the use of the back camera?

Comment: No, you cannot enforce that - the contract for this intent is very explicit and intentionally minimal, but even then many apps that manifest support for this contract, don't comply fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select a specific camera using **MediaStreamTrack.getSources()** API, getting the ID of the front/rear camera based on "facing" attribute.

Then use this ID in the constraints object passed to the navigator.getUserMedia() API to capture output from that camera.

```
var constraints;

MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(sourceInfos) {
    var videoSourceId = null;
    for (var i = 0; i != sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
        var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        // find rear camera
        if (sourceInfo.kind == "video" && sourceInfo.facing == "environment") {
            videoSourceId = sourceInfo.id;
        }
    }
    constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
          optional: [{sourceId: videoSourceId}]
        }
     }
});


navigator.getUserMedia(constraints,
    function(stream) {
       ...
    }

);
```